# Canonical sheaf not globally generated for a certain surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Me and a friend tried the following problem, but with no luck. Anything would be appreciated:

> Let $X \rightarrow S$ be an arithmetic surface such that for some $s \in S$, $X_s$ is the union of two elliptic curves meeting transversally at a point rational over $k(s)$. Show that $\omega_{X/S}$ is not generated by its global sections, and find the smallest $n$ such that $\omega^n_{X/S}$ is.

I have only noted some trivial things, the fibers are of genus two seems relevant. But apart from that, nothing.

Comment: @QiL'8: Am I correct in that there are no global sections when we are over a field?

Comment: @QiL'8: Thanks, I do not see why there aren't enough sections though ( I am quite confused).